# Trunk build fails for the simplest example

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, yew, trunk-rs

I am trying to learn to use Trunk and Yew so I  tried to follow a very simple example of Trunk, created a neatly empty index.html in the root of my rust project (just  the main tags  and  made trunk build

the thing fails with:
trunk  build
2023-03-13T16:56:38.507326Z  INFO  starting build
2023-03-13T16:56:38.507905Z  INFO spawning asset pipelines
2023-03-13T16:56:38.643288Z  INFO building rust-frontend-example-yew
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.07s
2023-03-13T16:56:38.773599Z  INFO fetching cargo artifacts
2023-03-13T16:56:38.915318Z ERROR ❌ error
error from HTML pipeline

Caused by:
0: error from asset pipeline
1: could not find WASM output after cargo build
Error: error from HTML pipeline

Caused by:
0: error from asset pipeline
1: could not find WASM output after cargo build

There is nothing in /dist

I cannot find ANYONE in the internet with this exact error and I am at loss on why the simplest  example fails.  Does anyone have a clue on what I can look for?

I already installed wasm-bindgen-cli by cargo install  btw.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I tried to serve a combined project of lib and bin:

```rust
// src/lib.rs
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component]
pub fn App() -> Html {
    ...
}
```

```rust
// src/main.rs
use project::App;

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

```ini
#Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[[bin]]
name = "bin"
path = "src/main.rs"

[dependencies]
yew = { version = "0.21.0", features = ["csr"] }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link data-trunk rel="rust" data-bin="bin" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Yew App</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

The index.html file needs
`<link data-trunk rel="rust" data-bin="bin" />`

and I had to update the wasm-bindgen-cli:

`cargo install -f wasm-bindgen-cli`